# cmd file for reading in folder and save specific filename as string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I currently try to write a short cmd file, which finds a specific file extension in a folder and saves the whole file name as a string, so it can then start a python script. This is what I have:

```
for %i in (*.py) do set filename= %i

"C:\Users\blabla\python.exe" %filename
```

I was looking for hours for a solution and this was the closest I got. I can't imagine, that it is that difficult.
Actually I don't even need the for loop, since only one .py file is in the concerning folder, but I didn't manage to find a solution. The *.py file changes from time to time depending on which version is used. Just clicking the cmd file would be easier than typing "C:\Users\blabla\python.exe" %filename by my own everytime, that's why I want to use a cmd file.
It's just for playing around and learn how to use cmd prompt works

What I want written as an example:

```
§get whole filename of file with .py extension§
set filename = XY.py
§run 
"C:\Users\blabla\python.exe" %filename
```

Comment: An environment variable is read by enclosing its name in between `%`-signs, so `%filename` is wrong, it should read `%filename%` to expand it to the previously assigned value. You need the `for` loop for resolving the global wildcard `*`. But `for %i in (*.py) do …` searches for `.py` files in the *current working directory* – is that what you want? use `for %i in ("D:\path\to\dir\*.py") do …` to specify a full directory path. Anyway, to assign the variable to a full path, use `set filename=%~fi` (no _space_!), or, even better, `set "filename=%~fi"`…

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I really named it "a" in the first place, so no wonder %a%  didn't work.

Comment: If this is a `.cmd` file, then you need to change all instances of your metavariable, `%i` to use two `%` characters!